# How to convert this Scala code to Scheme?

Tags: scala, scheme, racket

In Scala, I have this `type Set = Int => Boolean` how do I/can I mimic that in Scheme?

For instance, in Scala, I have

```
def singletonSet(elem: Int): Set = (x: Int) => (x == elem)
```

`def union(x: Set, y: Set): Set = (z: Int) => (x(z) || y(z))`

```
 def forall(s: Set, p: Int => Boolean): Boolean = {
    def iter(a: Int): Boolean = {
      if (a > bound) true
      else if (s(a) && !p(a)) false
      else iter(a + 1)
    }
    iter(-bound)
  }
```

In scheme, this is what I have so far:

```
    (define (singletonSet elem) (lambda (x) (= x elem)))
    (define (union x y) (lambda (z) (or (x z) (y z))))
    (define bound 1000)
    (define -bound 1000)

    (define (forall s p)
      (local ((define (iter a)
                (cond
                  [(> a bound) true]
                  [(and (s a) (not (p a))) false] 
                  [else (iter (+ a 1))])))
      (iter -bound)))
    (forall v (lambda (x) (= (modulo x 3) 0)))
```

So can you do `type Set = Int => Boolean` in Scheme/Racket?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Scheme, instead of `type Set = Int => Boolean` you need to write nothing at all: . The only reason Scala needs it is to write the argument and return types, neither of which you can do in Scheme. However, there is [Typed Racket](http://docs.racket-lang.org/ts-guide/), which adds static types to Racket and where you would write

```
(define-type Set (Integer -> Boolean))
```